# String cannot be converted to double error java

Tags: java, string

My code is suppose to read up to 100 string and store the values in an array. 
When an empty string is entered it stops reading information from a user. 
Then it validates the strings, converts to double numbers and is stored into a separate array. 
Then the average of all valid numbers is found. 
The only things that are printed are:
1) the number of valid strings entered 
2) all valid strings in reverse order they were inputed 
and 
3) the average of all valid inputs.

I think I have it okay, except when converting the strings into double numbers. I placed that into a try/catch along with everything else after that because otherwise it can't find the valid inputs. 
I am getting an error:(48: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double).
I have tried adding an else to my if statement but it doesn't connect the if and else statements. Though when I add the else statement the error goes away and it just tells me the only error is that it cannot find the if for the else.

What can I do?

EDIT: Thank you, it works now. But I don't think I am finding the average correctly. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Grades{
public static void main(String args[]){ 


  int arraycount = 0;
  final int SIZE = 10;
  int validArraycount = 0;
  final int ValidArraySize = 10;
  int valuesinValidArray = 0; 

  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  String initialInput = new String ("");

  String [] sArray = new String[SIZE];
  double [] ValidArray = new double[ValidArraySize];

  double sum = 0;

  boolean exit = false;

  System.out.println("You may enter up to 100 grades."); 
  System.out.println("When you are done entering grades, press the enter/return key.");


  //Prints to user. Stops if nothing is entered.
  while((arraycount < SIZE)&&(exit == false)){ 
     System.out.println("Enter line " + (arraycount+1) + ": "); 
     initialInput = reader.nextLine();  


     if (initialInput.length()<1){ 
        exit = true; 
     }
     else{
        sArray[arraycount]=initialInput; 
        arraycount++;
     }
  }

     //convert string to double 
  try{
     double convertedInput = Double.parseDouble(initialInput);

     //validate strings entered by user         
     if(convertedInput >= 0 && convertedInput <=100){
      ValidArray[validArraycount] = initialInput;
     }      

     //Prints number of valid values entered
     if(ValidArray.length>0){
        System.out.println("The number of valid grades entered is " + ValidArray[0]);
     }


     //for printing array backwards
     for (int i = (arraycount-1); i>=0; i--){
        System.out.print(ValidArray.length);

     } 
     //calculates sum of all values in array of ValidArray (of grades)
     for(double d : ValidArray){
        sum += sum;
     }

      //avergae of valid number array 
     double average = (sum/ValidArray.length);

     System.out.println("Average: " + average);

  }

  catch(NumberFormatException e){
  }   
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner at Java, so excuse my stupidity, but how would a scanner help? I am using a scanner to get strings from a user. Do I need another? and if so then for what?

Answer (score 1):

`ValidArray[validArraycount] = initialInput;`

is probably supposed to be

`ValidArray[validArraycount] = convertedInput;`

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
ValidArray[validArraycount] = initialInput;
```

You are trying to assign a String to an array of `doubles`. This is where the error is coming. You can try calling `double.parseDouble(initialInput)` on this if you are sure it will be a double in String form.

Comment: Two lines before that. Doesn't that line convert the strings to double?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning the wrong value to your array. Replace:

```
ValidArray[validArraycount] = initialInput;
```

With:

```
ValidArray[validArraycount] = convertedInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, to fix your String conversion issue, you're assignment line should be:

```
ValidArray[validArraycount] = convertedInput;
```

To fix your average problem, your code should look like this:

```
//calculates sum of all values in array of ValidArray (of grades)
for(double d : ValidArray){
   sum += d;  //  <-------- changed from sum += sum;
}

//avergae of valid number array 
double average = (sum/ValidArray.length);
```